# Inverse of php array_column function?

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array like

```
$x = array(array('a', 'aa'), array('b', 'bb'), array('c', 'cc'));
```

There is `array_column` that returns either

```
array_column($x, 0) === array('a', 'b', 'c')

or 

array_column($x, 1) === array('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
```

Now, is there an inverse? A function that would do:

```
array_putoneaftertheother(array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('aa', 'bb', 'cc')) === array(array('a', 'aa'), array('b', 'bb'), array('c', 'cc'))
```

None come to my mind...

It's pretty easy to implement, but I'm surprised that with so many `array_*` functions, PHP has no native version of this?!

Comment: A side note: I wouldn't really call it inverse of `array_column()`. `array_column()` returns a "vertical slice". Inverse/opposite of this would be a horizontal slice (or maybe everything except that column, but let's not go there), which is just `$x[n]`. What you described seems like rotating a 2D array, so rows become columns and columns become rows.

Comment: @akinuri I called this "inverse" because then `array_column(array_putoneaftertheother($x, $y), 0) === $x` so like `f • g = Id` meaning `f` function is `g` inverse. Opposite would be `f•g=0` Tho you may indeed consider this as a `transpose` function of the `array('a','b','c')` vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do multiple arrays with `array_map` and no callback:

```
$result = array_map(null, array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('aa', 'bb', 'cc'));
```

Or with one larger array the same way with [Argument unpacking via ...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (splat operator):

```
$result = array_map(null, ...array(array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('aa', 'bb', 'cc')));
```

Comment: Oh, indeed! I didn't got the "NULL [...] perform a zip operation on multiple arrays" of the doc, but I should have digged more into the examples, as this is the example #4 and #5 of doc https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php Thanks !